# How to integrate Business Process Server with wso2 identity server?

Tags: process, integration, identity

I am working on integration process of wso2 BPS with wso2 IS. Basically my requirement is to add workflow feature in user management process. For example if one admin modifies user profiles, another admin approval is required further.

Now what is the process of integrating wso2 BPS component with wso2 IS?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you already have a process designed in WSO2 Business Process Server. Now you need to 'integrate', so that the approved modifications are indeed applied in the WSO2 Identity Server.

WSO2 Identity server provides several administrative services. One of these services is called UserAdmin. My thought would be to invoke these services once you have a modification that has been approved.

More info on the available WSO2 Identity Server's webservices here: http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/10/wsas-hiddedn-services.html